# how to download just one part of a txt file in java?

Tags: java, io

Is it possible to download just the first 50 lines of a .txt file in java?
If possible, I'd need a solution without external libraries, compatible with Java 5 and as simple as possible (involving lines of text rather than streams... one can dream!)

Comment: How do you expect it to be done without streams? If you want to do something in real time, you need streams... or you can download the full file...

Comment: What do you mean by "download"? HTTP, FTP, Web Service, WebDAV, ...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Certainly it's possible, just read the first 50 lines and then stop reading.

You can't do it without streams, since that's what will happen underneath anyways, but a regular `new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8")));` (select the proper encoding) will work just fine.

Comment: Nitpick: with a BufferedReader you might actually read more than 50 lines worth of data because more data might get buffered than you actually consume from the reader ;)

Comment: @Gimby Well if we're getting technical, you could always initialize `BufferedReader` with a buffersize of 1.

Comment: Touche. You'd effectively disable buffering, but you'd still have access to the useful readLine() method.